# subtract a datetime from a timestamp with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to do a subtraction between two fields from two different tables, one of the field is a 
Datetime the other field is a Timestamp.

What's the best way to achieve that ?

convert first to unix timestamp ?

something like:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.col1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.col2) from t1, t2 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) is by far the most versatile alternative.

```
select timestampdiff(SECOND, t1.col1, t2.col2);
```

See it in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9a58/3)